# Python: How to handle a repeating function on the main thread requesting updates from multiple sub-threads each execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Situation: This is the structure of a code I'm working on, it uses Tkinter but I left the details out to keep it simple and related to the threading question. The main thread contains a function we'll call `calculate` which repeatedly calls itself every second... each call it creates a number of threads running `thread_func`, they all do the heavy lifting on a common task, this task is divided based on the number of the thread so each thread only works on parts assigned to it. When a thread finishes it uses the `Pipe()` function to send the result back (`Queue()` is ridiculously slow for large data), the main thread waits until it has received this result from all threads before it will continue and reschedule itself.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import tkinter as tk

    class Viewport:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.thread_count = mp.cpu_count()
            self.p1, self.p2 = mp.Pipe(duplex = False)
            self.calculate()

        def thread_func(self, i: int):
            # something.heavy_stuff does the difficult repetitive task, it only processes parts of data matching the i number of the core
            var result = something.heavy_stuff(i)
            self.p2.send(result)

        def calculate(self):
            # 1: Start all threads
            threads = {}
            for i in range(0, self.thread_count):
                threads[i] = mp.Process(target = self.thread_func, args = (i,))
                threads[i].start()

            # 2: Wait until all threads have delivered their data
            for i in range(0, self.thread_count):
                self.p1.recv()

            # 3: Stop threads
            for i in self.processes:
                self.processes[i].join()

            self.root.after(1000, self.calculate)
```

Issue: Although this appears to work fine, I'm uncomfortable with joining and creating so many threads every second... especially when the end result is designed to run at any speed so it could even be 1ms, I don't know if some operating systems may be upset by an application adding or deleting over a dozen processes many times a second. It would be ideal if I could create all threads just once, have them indefinitely run in the background, and only close everything when the program exits. This was originally the case: Everything inside `thread_func` was in a `while True:` loop, #1 where I start the threads was located in `__init__` instead of `calculate`, and point #3 didn't exist so I didn't stop the threads... I also used a `Lock()` so the `calculate` function paused the threads in sync and the received signal count at point #2 always matches expectations. This doesn't work for a few reasons:

1. The running thread is unable to see changes to variables in the main thread, once started a thread exists in its own parallel reality based on the past of the main thread at the moment the sub-thread was created... hence I'm using the pipe as it's the only way to send data over. Every time the `calculate` func reruns on the main thread, I want all threads it requests an update from to see changes in other variables (such as those in `self`) that happened on the main thread.
2. Using a `while True:` loop in `thread_func` causes my program to be unable to shut down unless forced to. As there's no easy way to change something in an already running thread from the main thread and vice-versa, there's no way to let sub-threads know I want to quit. I tried using the pipe backwards with `duplex = True` but no matter the order of the pipes that would cause weird errors and crashes.

My question is: How do you think I should structure this code to work correctly? Should I go with the current model as I exemplified it, where a function on the main thread calling itself often destroys old threads and creates new ones each time... or is there a way to design this so the main thread may keep all sub-threads active during the duration of the application, but have those threads detect and changes in `self.*` variables and know when I'm exiting the program so they don't block it?

Comment: if you want all threads at once then maybe use `ThreadPool` , or create thread only once and use `pipe` or `queue` to send data and to get result - and later don't delete thread but send new data and get new result, etc. And thread should run loop which gets new data, make calculations and send result, and it go back to the beginning to get new data, etc. You can use some data to inform thread that this is end of work - to stop all code - you can send text `"quit"` to thread and it has to check it and `break` loop.

Comment: Thanks: `multiprocessing.Pool()` seems to be exactly what I was looking for, it's even better suited for my task than using a pipe or queue... other options I attempted and didn't work or couldn't manage to try successfully. At the moment I can't seem to get Python threat pools to work in any form, none of the online examples function for me... if anyone's interested here is my new question about those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609981/python-thread-pools-not-working-pool-map-freezes-pool-map-async-returns-a-mapr