# Python thread pools not working: pool.map freezes, pool.map_async returns a MapResult that's not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to use the `multiprocessing.Pool()` function as it seems most fit for my project. I've followed several tutorial articles on how it works and attempted their examples. Some that I'm referring to:

https://superfastpython.com/threadpool-python

https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-map

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-pool-map-multiple-arguments

https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/multiprocessing-using-pool-in-python

Somehow all examples provided there by seemingly experienced programmers are broken: Whenever I try to run them just as described, my application freezes or errors out. Based on what those resources suggested I compiled the following test:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def double(i):
    return i * 2

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for result in pool.map(double, [1, 2, 3]):
        print(result)

main()
```

This causes the application to spawn a lot of processes and then freeze. None of those processes are even using any CPU as if they're stuck processing something: They just sit there idly forever. I tried using `pool.map_async` instead of `pool.map` out of curiosity, now I instead get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'MapResult' object is not iterable
```

Strange since none of those examples mentioned there should be a `MapResult` object that cannot be iterated. But one suggested using `result.get()` instead: I did that and the result is that even with map_async everything just freezes again.

```
pool = mp.Pool()
result = pool.map(double, [1, 2, 3])
print(result)
```

Removing the for loop in favor of printing the result directly has the exact same behavior: If I use `pool.map` everything freezes forever, if I use `pool.map_async` I'm told it's a `MapResult` unless I try to print `result.get()` in which case everything freezes again. Exact same two issues exist when getting the data with either `pool.apply(double)` or `pool.apply_async(double)` instead. Any idea what both myself seemingly every tutorial on Python thread pools are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that is at top-level is run my every process.  You need to make sure that your `main()` is only by the main thread.

The simple solution is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: How so, considering `main()` is executed from the root file and only the `double()` function is given to a thread? The problem with `if __name__ == '__main__'` is that it causes the block to never run at all: I tried keeping that but everything is completely ignored... my script is ran locally from a bash console if that is relevant, eg: `python3 ./init.py`

Comment: Got it: The line `if __name__ == '__main__':` needs to be located in the exact Python file you're executing, it won't work in an included script even if it's still on the main thread. I'm doing this inside a class located in another library so it might get a little tricky, please let me know what the best solution is. But I can confirm that simple example now works directly in `init.py` when ran.

Comment: Sorry, you answered your question before I could.  The important thing is that main() needs to be called only once.  The magic `if` above is only true in the file that is the main execution target.  So if you typed `python init.py`, it is only true in `init.py`.  Multiprocessing uses a different method of execution, so in subprocesses, the magic `if` is always false.