# Python: Can multiprocessing.Pool() be used in modules other than '__main__'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have the following simple case of using a thread pool:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def double(i):
    return i * 2

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for result in pool.map(double, [1, 2, 3]):
        print(result)

main()
```

For over a day I've been trying to figure out why running that code would cause freezing and errors. Then in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609981/python-thread-pools-not-working-pool-map-freezes-pool-map-async-returns-a-mapr) about the crash, someone pointed out the code needs to be filtered behind a `__name__ == '__main__'` check.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In fact if I put the original code in `init.py` which I execute from the console, it works even without this if statement. But there's a problem: I want to use `multiprocessing.Pool()` inside a class in another script which `init.py` imports with `import myotherscript` then creates an instance of a class from: In this case `__name__` is no longer `'__main__'` but the name of this other script, even if I call a function in it from `init.py` anything defined in this other script will has a different name.

Is there a way to use the multithreading pool inside a module? Or does Python only allow pools to run in the init file being executed? If it's a hard limitation I'll need to define my library directly under `init.py` but that would be wrong and ugly code structuring so hopefully there exists a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to use multiprocessing from modules. Just don't run code *in the body of the module* (outside of any function) unless you want it to run on the startup of each worker in the pool. In particular, don't run the code that creates a new pool there.

Normally, in a module, you don't do that in the first place. It's only in the main file that you usually have that problem.

But it does push a similar requirement up to the *user* of your module. Say your module defines a class `Cluster` and does `self.pool = mp.Pool()` in `__init__`, and then someone writes a program that looks like

```
#!python
import yourmodule

c = yourmodule.Cluster()
c.compute("something")
```

then that program will explode. Instead they have to write

```
#!python
import yourmodule

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = yourmodule.Cluster()
    c.compute("something")
```

which will avoid calling the `Cluster` constructor on worker startup, and therefore avoid trying to create pools within pools.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try going with something among those lines. Problem is that the cluster class (once instanced from main) is supposed to call the internally defined threaded tasks on its own, in a controlled fashion of course but based on its own internal loops and triggers (eg: once every 1 second). Is there a way to achieve that as well, or can the thread function only be triggered from main?

Comment: @MirceaKitsune yes, sure, it can do whatever it wants, so long as *the thing that kicks all that work off* isn't triggered merely by importing a module. Creating a timer on instantiation is fine, as long as the instantiation is guarded. Everything is fine, as long as it doesn't happen when multiprocessing tries to `import` the top-level script as a module.